# BlocBuilder not rebuilding UI after change

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a BlocBuilder that draws a donation strip, but when a change to a donation comes from the socket, for some reason it does not redraw the UI after calling emit.

bloc

```
BlocBuilder<PatientCardBloc, PatientCardState>(
                    bloc: PatientCardBloc(),
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return DonatedProgress(
                        name: patient.firstName,
                        disease: patient.problem.disease,
                        currentAmount:
                            state.status != PatientCardStatus.initialized
                                ? patient.currentAmount
                                : patient.id == state.patient.id
                                    ? state.patient.currentAmount
                                    : patient.currentAmount,
                        totalAmount: patient.amount,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

emit

```
_onSetPatientCardFromSoketEvent(
      SetPatientCardFromSoketEvent event, Emitter<PatientCardState> emit) {
    final patient = event.patient;
    if (state.patient.id == patient.id) {
      emit(PatientCardState(
          patient: patient, status: PatientCardStatus.initialized));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is your if true? Does it jump inside to emit the state?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Yes, I checked. If you output the state before emit and after, then currentAmount will be different

Answer (score 1):

> bloc: PatientCardBloc()

You should not create a new Bloc object while defining BlocBuilder. Use BlocProvider's create method instead.

Comment: The problem is not that, but that I do not rebuild the bloc after emit